# How to hide URL in adress bar when I use <a href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, angularjs, asp.net-mvc

I have several documents stored in a folder in a project using ASP MVC 5. The HTML link to see the document is:

```
<a ng-href="~/download/document/{{vm.document}}"><a/>
```

Then this URL will see it in adress bar:
`http://localhost:20870/download/document/d47a1c96-e4d7-423b-aa83-76537c392ad2.pdf`

For safety I do not want this URL is visible!

Comment: If its not in the url, it will not be passed to the method!

Comment: You can put htaccess ignore inside you document folder, so no one can reach it alone

Comment: For the download to work the URL has to be publicly available. If you want to restrict access to the file, then it sounds like you need to use a token system where the server reads a provided token and checks that it's valid, before redirecting to the file to be downloaded.

Comment: If it's about security, the user can always look at the page source to find the secret URL.

Comment: Do you mean the pdf link appears in the status bar at the bottom when mouseover it?

Answer (score 2):

As others pointed out, URLs are meant to be public. There is no reasonable way to completely hide them from the user.

However, you *can* use MVC to control access to *resources*, such as physical files.

By default MVC does not serve physical files, IIS serves them directly. Assuming that your file is physically located in the `/download/document/` virtual directory, start by blocking any direct access to the folder through your root `web.config` file.

```
<location path="download/document">
    <system.web>
        <authorization>
            <deny users="*" />
        </authorization>
    </system.web>
</location>
```

This ensures that no user (whether logged in or not) can access the file directly through IIS.

Then, you can use a controller action method in conjunction with the `[Authorize]` attribute to control who has access to the file.

```
public class SecureDownloadController : Controller
{
    [Authorize]
    public ActionResult Document(string id)
    {
        return File(@"D:\wwwroot\documents\download\" + id, "application/pdf");
    }
}
```

The above will allow any logged on user to access the file at the URL `http://localhost:20870/securedownload/document/d47a1c96-e4d7-423b-aa83-76537c392ad2.pdf`.

> **IMPORTANT:** Never use a *real* location for the file in the URL. IIS will favor a physical location to an MVC controller action, so if the physical file exists you will get an error. You probably don't want the user to know the physical location of the file anyway.

You could further restrict it to a specific user role or roles by using:

```
[Authorize(Roles = "Admin,SuperUser")]
```

Alternatively, you could subclass `[Authorize]` attribute and use some other way to secure the file, for example, passing a hash code through the HTTP headers.

Another possible alternative: [Generate the PDF as a stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name) rather than using a physical file that is persisted on the disk. This ensures there is no physical path where the file can be accessed - it can only be accessed through a controller action method. It also ensures you never have to clean up a directory of one-time-use PDF files.

References:

- [Protecting folders in MVC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10794980/protecting-folders-in-mvc)
- [Download file of any type in Asp.Net MVC using FileResult?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3604562/download-file-of-any-type-in-asp-net-mvc-using-fileresult)
- [Stream file using ASP.NET MVC FileContentResult in a browser with a name?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3206682/stream-file-using-asp-net-mvc-filecontentresult-in-a-browser-with-a-name)

Answer (score 0):

Dear url hiding will not benefitial because we can know the details of request by pressing F12 on network tab.

[image]

Protect your document in a better way. I think role based security will be good and give access to document depends on Request.

Answer (score 0):

You Should Use This

`<a href="javascript:void(0)" onclick="location.href='" . $ajax_like_link . "'">Link</a>`